# use two different startActivityForResult within two different activity

Tags: android

I don't really know how to say it, I'll just describe it with pic

[image]

this is how it works:

```
edittext1 (Enter) -> Listview1 (choose item) -> back to first activity with item from activityA
```

same with the second one

```
edittext2 (Enter) -> Listview2 (choose item) -> back to first activity with item from activityB
```

I tried to use `startActivityForResult(set, 0);` and `startActivityForResult(set, 1);` but it didn't work at all

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
    if(resultCode == 0) {
    //do things for first edittext
    }
    else if(resultCode == 1) {
    //do things for second edittext
    }
}
```

on `activityA` and `activityB` I use this to get their item and bring back to first activity

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("namaDokter", "kosong");
setResult(RESULT_OK, i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to check the request code, not the result code

the result code is a general code signalling, whether or not the activity finished correctly.
The request code is the code that you pass to the new activity in order to differentiate when it finishes.

So basically, you should use something like:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
   if (requestCode == 0) {
     // do things for first edittext
   } else if (requestCode == 1) {
     //do things for second edit text
   }
  } else {
    // the activity didn't finish with result ok
  }
 }
```

Comment: Well, I can't accept answer immediately, I have to wait two minutes

Answer (score 0):

First you shoud use the @Override anotation above onActivityResult. Second you should check the request code for 0, 1 or whatever code you started the activity. The result code should be compared to Activity.RESULT_OK.

Comment: I've tried that but it didn't work. I already got answer, but thanks for your help :)